# Redirect to Android application after successful payment

Tags: cordova, redirect

I have successfully implemented payment gateway in the web version of a web app. While doing the same for android application (cordova/phonegap) I am lost at a point when the redirect happens after success/failure payment.

Web version has URLs to capture response but how do we achieve this in android app? The PG provider says they do not provide android SDK for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using Inapp browser plugin you should be able to achive this.

[Inapp browser plugin documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 let browser = window.open('https://www.payumoney.com/paybypayumoney/#/asdasd', '_self', 'location=yes' );
 browser.addEventListener('loadstart',function(event){
 console.log(event);
   if (event["url"] == "http://localhost:3000/capture_successfull_payment") {
       console.log(event);
       // browser.close();
        } else if (event["url"] == "http://localhost:3000/capture_cancelled_payment"){
       }
    })
```